# How to slow down and speed up time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I implemented an example of how to pause time in JavaScript. The example is here http://jsfiddle.net/suska/n4g5U/

```
// Update of Date class to modify getTime method.
Date.prototype.origGetTime = Date.prototype.getTime;
Date._lastPausedAt;
Date._stopDuration = 0;
Date.prototype.getTime = function() {
    if (Date._lastPausedAt) {
        return Date._lastPausedAt.origGetTime() - Date._stopDuration;
    }
    return new Date().origGetTime() - Date._stopDuration;
};
Date.isPaused = function() {
    return Date._lastPausedAt != null;
};
Date.pause = function() {
    if (!Date._lastPausedAt) {
        Date._lastPausedAt = new Date();
    }               
};
Date.unpause = function() {
    if (Date._lastPausedAt) {
        Date._stopDuration += new Date().origGetTime() - Date._lastPausedAt.origGetTime();
        Date._lastPausedAt = null;
    }
};
```

Any idea how can I modify the example to do a slow down and speed up functionality?

Comment: _pause time_? _Mother of God._

Comment: Why are you using a `Date` object for this?

Comment: You are really doing a very bda job. But anyways, if you want, Just change the duration of animate: _$('h1').animate({'marginLeft': 200}, **2000**, animateToLeft);_

Comment: I want to control global time in JavaScript and other JavaScript functions use Date.getTime for it.

Comment: no real reasons for override Date.prototype.getTime

Comment: He uses `Date` object because he wants to interract with jquery animation functions which use `Date` object. It is an interesting way to increase / decrease jquery animations speeds without manage all the animations durations.

Comment: @dooxe it's also an interesting way to break everything else that uses `Date.prototype.getTime`.  I've heard a lot of people pontificate about the evil inherent in extending native JS objects' prototypes, but I suppose I assumed that actually *overriding* their methods was such a terrible idea that it didn't need to be said.  If there wasn't a character requirement for answers, mine would be: "Don't do that."

Comment: He asked if there was a way to slow or accelerate the time using Date, for jquery animations, I so gave him a way to do that. But it is true that it's not a good thing to override Date prototype functions (or other native object).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrote a variant on dooxe's answer to avoid the sudden jumps when changing between time warps.

```
var milli = Date.prototype.getTime;
var lastTime = (new Date).getTime();
var curTime = 0;
Date.prototype.getTime = function(){
    var actualTime = milli.call(this);
    curTime += (actualTime - lastTime) * Date._speed;
    lastTime = actualTime;
    return curTime;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick to 'override' `Date.getTime` function :

```
var milli = Date.prototype.getTime;
Date.prototype.getTime = function(){
    return milli.call(this) * 5;  
};
```

Use a factor (5 in my code) inferior to 1 to slow the time :

http://jsfiddle.net/uKk9R/

Comment: It doesn't work smoothly when I'm changing the speed value http://jsfiddle.net/suska/uKk9R/1/