# Is It Possible To Detect Injected Javascript Via Console?

Tags: javascript

Say I was, or somebody was to **inject custom Javascript on my website via the console.** To say fire the Facebook pixel via Javascript. Or to simulate real mouse movement via Javascript.

**Is it possible for the website to detect this has been done?**

Comment: Not really. You can detect, if someone pressed F12, or if the window size was changed as if someone opened a console, but that's all

Comment: You can't even know for sure that your site content was loaded by a web browser.

Comment: F12? Useless. The site can be opened with console already open. Detect resize? minimize and maximize send regards. To stop this only in a browser without console. But the browser is in client side... and the war continues ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The developer's console is entirely temporary. Now let's say that you created a function that is run off of a server, let's say a function that sends a message to other people on the same server, (ie. Instant Messaging). If you send a message through a server, then it can be seen, but that is only if you send the message through a server. But if you just type a function into the console that returns the words, "Hello, World" that can not be seen by anyone. So, in conclusion, if you use a function hooked up to a server, that sends data back to the server, then yes, it can be seen, but like the example you gave, the Facebook Pixel, that is sent from Facebook, but implement it in your site; it is run from the server from Facebook, not your website.

Comment: So executing events on the FB pixel from JavaScript in the console, is like the actual website was doing it itself? FB wouldn't know the difference?

Comment: Websites would be able to detect mouse movement right via Javascript? Then relay this back to their website. If someone is clicking elements, without any mouse movement, then this is a red flag? Possibility a bot?

Comment: If the website it's self has implemented bot detection.

Comment: How much info do websites have to detect say bot cursor movement? Is it simply just the "mousemove" event? If I decided to move the cursor with Javascript. I know it won't physically move it. However, inside the website, it would appear so. Would websites be able to detect I was doing that?

Comment: It seems you want to run a cursor bot. If you want to do that then use python. Use a library like OpenCV or pyautogui

Comment: I'm using selenium webdriver and java.. So I'm sorta limited to what I can work with.

Comment: Would I have to physically move the mouse? As that means I am limited to 1 instance of Chrome at a time :(

Comment: Could you give me more information about your problem?

Comment: I have a question on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456577/selenium-webdriver-java-simulate-human-like-cursor-movement

Comment: Set a delay, lets say use a timeout function [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). Create a function that waits a cretian amout of time than clicks. You can also set the speed of your mouse in a function that sets the time and slows it time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023892/how-to-slow-down-and-speed-up-time-in-javascript).

Comment: I will repeat though, Python would be better. But here is a link that describes facebook's bot detection: https://mc.ai/how-does-facebook-detect-bots/

Comment: What about something like this? https://css-tricks.com/simulating-mouse-movement/

Comment: Just would FB be able to detect I was moving the mouse via Javascript?

Comment: I have managed to do it via AutoIt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474446/autoit-automation-how-to-simulate-human-like-cursor-movement

Comment: Look at the comments. Someone suggested a link to a script. I have tried it and it works. But I would have to call an .exe file every time I wanted to move the mouse in my Java

Comment: Then I would be limited to 1 instance of chrome at a time

Comment: I don't think it's possible to move the actual mouse cursor in Javascript. I have read many stack overflows hammering this point. It makes sense. As it would be a huge security risk.

Comment: It is impossable to move the currsor with javascript.

Comment: Yes, I have discovered this too.

Comment: But I do got to say, Thanks for the upvotes. It really helped.